# How to generate and mail the permanent password in Drupal 8?

Tags: drupal-8

It is necessary when the user register automatically generate him a permanent password, which can be used. Then send it to the address indicated when registering mail

Answer (score 0):

Emailing a user password after initial registration *can* be done, but by default Drupal makes this process hard since emailing passwords is a poor security practice. Instead Drupal emails a password reset link that allows the user to login and change the password just after registration.

That said, you could override that behavior by creating a custom module that implements [`hook_entity_presave()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_presave/8.2.x), changes the password and triggers an email before the new user entity is saved.

Comment: Thank you. If you are not difficult to point out examples of such functionality on the Internet

Comment: Sure there are sites on the internet that do that, but that doesn't change the fact that it's a poor practice that encourages people to treat email as a secure means of communication.

Comment: Emailing plain text passwords is a security disaster!